# how can i save the codes in colab and it's permissions

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory, restriction

I want to save my codes and i want to restrict it that no one can change it even myself.
I don't know how to do it. is it possible?
I know how to share without edit permission. but how to do it for myself

Comment: Why would you need to restrict even yourself?

Answer (score 0):

There's a Playground Mode in Colab (check *File* menu), it still allows you to run and change everything but nothing will be saved, that applies to output too. You can also create links to Playground mode Colab Notebooks yourself by appending `#forceEdit=true&sandboxMode=true` to the URL, i.e `colab.research.google.com/drive/1R4O...?hl=en#forceEdit=true&sandboxMode=true`  and perhaps collect those links into single Notebook and access those files from there.

But even if you accidentally do mess up your Notebook, in most cases you can still roll back to pervious revision through *Revision history* , you can name revisions and manually save & pin your Notebook.

Colab also integrates with Github and you can conveniently save the copy there as well for proper version control - *File >> Save a Copy in Github*
Works with private repositories and Github Gists too. And by default the *"Open In Colab"*  button is added to those files, so no need to manually re-import anything to Colab or GDrive.